# Migrations error: changes detected but nothing changed in my database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, connection, django-migrations

I'm trying to connect my django project with mongodb database, after migrations the changes detected but nothing happen in my database.
I'm providing the models.py and setting.py files, if anyone can help me and thank you in advance.
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description=models.TextField()
    deadline=models.DateField()
    done=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'Coll'
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'Mydb',
    }
}
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'
```

I already installed djongo, and this is my **pip list**

```
Django                4.2
django-cors-headers   3.14.0
django-grappelli      3.0.5
django-mongodb-engine 0.6.0
django-suit           2.0a2
djangorestframework   3.14.0
djangotoolbox         1.8.0
djongo                1.3.6
grep                  0.3.2
mongoengine           0.27.0
Pillow                9.5.0
pip                   23.0.1
pipenv                2023.3.20
pymongo               3.12.1
pytz                  2023.3
sqlparse              0.4.3
virtualenv            20.21.0
virtualenv-clone      0.5.7
```

Comment: run the following commands and post their output: `python3 manage.py makemigrations` & `python3 manage.py migrate`